# Targeting an image from link

Tags: javascript, html

I have a standard `<a>` link on a web page. I'm trying to use the `onmouseover` to change an image elsewhere on the same page, but I'm not getting anywhere.

I'm guessing this is possible, but how?

Comment: I think we will need more info - can you post some code please?

Comment: in plain old JS? Or can JQ be used? :-)

Comment: Image can be located by it's ID no matter where on the page it is. Inside your mouseover event handler use `getElementById` to locate the image. And show us what you have tried please

Comment: I suppose JS, because there is no tag for jQuery, @deadconversations

Comment: Yes, but judging by the style of his question, it might be he doesn't know of JQ's existence.

Comment: To put a bit of flesh onto this.I have a very basic web page. The page has links and an image. The image has an id called "targetImage" with the links having ids of "link1", "link2", "link3". What I'm trying to do is when the mouse pointer is over the link, to change it to a target image and then revert back when the mouse is not on the link. As to what I have tried, as I'm not too good with JS, I'd tried a couple of CSS solutions, but nothing worked, so it is a case of using JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this JS code:

```
window.load = function() {
    var link = document.getElementById('LINK_ID');
    var img = document.getElementById('IMAGE_ID');

    link.onmouseover = function() {
        img.src = 'put image path here to change';
    }
}
```

Then if you wanna return back to old image, when user moves his mouse out of the link.

```
window.load = function() {
    var link = document.getElementById('LINK_ID');
    var img = document.getElementById('IMAGE_ID');
    var org_img = img.src;

    link.onmouseover = function() {
        img.src = 'put image path here to change';
    }

    link.onmouseout = function() {
        img.src = org_img;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go the inline route for a quick solution.

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="document.pic.src='Hover Image'" onmouseout ="document.pic.src='Original Image'">Change That Pic!</a>
```

And then the image itself would be added as

```
<img name=pic src="Original Image" />
```

[Fiddle Example Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/PLZNk/1/)